# how to simulate a table with 2 primary keys in mongoose when one item is another schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a 2 schema, the first is simple and the second contains the first.
I.E:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const factorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  factory: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  projectTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  projectDescription: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  factory: {
    type: factorySchema,
    required: true,
  },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('project', projectSchema);
```

I would like to make sure we do not have the same projectTitle in the same factory.
Two different factories can have the same project title.

I tried to use this validation -

```
  factory: {
    type: factorySchema,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: async function (project) {
        const ProjectModel = mongoose.model('project');
        const count = await ProjectModel.countDocuments({
          _id: { $ne: this._id }, // Exclude current document (during update)
          'factory.factory': project.factory,
          projectTitle: project.projectTitle,
        });

        return count === 0; // Return true if no other matching prompts found
      },
      message:
        'Another project with the same projectTitle already exists in this factory.',
    },
```

But I can't manage to compare the right factory value. It just ignores the condition as if

> 'factory.factory': project.factory,

Never happens. I manage to insert several objects with the same exact values.
Please help